Clarification on Deriving the Jacobi Identity for Poisson Brackets in Multiple Dimensions
I am currently working through an exercise to derive the Jacobi identity for Poisson brackets, and I decided to tackle the more general case in multiple dimensions. However, I am unsure whether my reasoning in the final step, where I cancel terms to obtain zero, is fully justified.
Below, I have included my derivation so far, using some simplified notations for clarity. My main question is: Have I correctly motivated the final cancellation of terms, or is there something I'm overlooking?
Any feedback or corrections would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance.
Derivation
To derive the Jacobi identity for Poisson brackets, I first introduce the simplified notations for partial derivatives,
\begin{align*}
    F_{q_i}&=\frac{\partial F}{{\partial q_i}}\quad\&\quad F_{{q_i}{p_i}} = \frac{\partial ^2F}{{\partial q_i}\partial {p_i}}\,.
\end{align*}
Analysing each term separately, first we have
\begin{align*}
\{f,g\} &= \sum_i f_{q_i} g_{p_i} - f_{p_i} g_{q_i}\,, \\
\{g,h\} &= \sum_i g_{q_i} h_{p_i} - g_{p_i} h_{q_i}\,, \\
\{h,f\} &= \sum_i h_{q_i} f_{p_i} - h_{p_i} f_{q_i}\,. \\
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
\{f,\{g,h\}\} &= \sum_j \left[f_{q_j}\sum_i(g_{q_i} h_{p_i} - g_{p_i} h_{q_i})_{p_j} - f_{p_j}\sum_i(g_{q_i} h_{p_i} - g_{p_i} h_{q_i})_{q_j}\right]\\
&= \sum_{i,j} \Big[ f_{q_j} \left( g_{q_i p_j} h_{p_i} + g_{q_i} h_{p_i p_j} - g_{p_i p_j} h_{q_i} - g_{p_i} h_{q_i p_j} \right) \\
&\quad - f_{p_j} \left( g_{q_i q_j} h_{p_i} + g_{q_i} h_{p_i q_j} - g_{p_i q_j} h_{q_i} - g_{p_i} h_{q_i q_j} \right) \Big]\,.
\end{align*}
Similarly, we get
\begin{align*}
\{g, \{h, f\}\} &= \sum_{i,j} \Big[ g_{q_j} \left( h_{q_i p_j} f_{p_i} + h_{q_i} f_{p_i p_j} - h_{p_i p_j} f_{q_i} - h_{p_i} f_{q_i p_j} \right) \\
&\quad - g_{p_j} \left( h_{q_i q_j} f_{p_i} + h_{q_i} f_{p_i q_j} - h_{p_i q_j} f_{q_i} - h_{p_i} f_{q_i q_j} \right) \Big]\,,
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\{h, \{f, g\}\} &= \sum_{i,j} \Big[ h_{q_j} \left( f_{q_i p_j} g_{p_i} + f_{q_i} g_{p_i p_j} - f_{p_i p_j} g_{q_i} - f_{p_i} g_{q_i p_j} \right) \\
&\quad - h_{p_j} \left( f_{q_i q_j} g_{p_i} + f_{q_i} g_{p_i q_j} - f_{p_i q_j} g_{q_i} - f_{p_i} g_{q_i q_j} \right) \Big]\,.
\end{align*}
Altogether, we get
\begin{align*}
\{f,\{g,h\}\} + \{g,\{h,f\}\} + \{h,\{f,g\}\} &= \sum_{i,j} \Big[ f_{q_j} \left( g_{q_i p_j} h_{p_i} + g_{q_i} h_{p_i p_j} - g_{p_i p_j} h_{q_i} - g_{p_i} h_{q_i p_j} \right) \\
&\quad - f_{p_j} \left( g_{q_i q_j} h_{p_i} + g_{q_i} h_{p_i q_j} - g_{p_i q_j} h_{q_i} - g_{p_i} h_{q_i q_j} \right) \Big]\\
&\quad +\sum_{i,j} \Big[ g_{q_j} \left( h_{q_i p_j} f_{p_i} + h_{q_i} f_{p_i p_j} - h_{p_i p_j} f_{q_i} - h_{p_i} f_{q_i p_j} \right) \\
&\quad\quad - g_{p_j} \left( h_{q_i q_j} f_{p_i} + h_{q_i} f_{p_i q_j} - h_{p_i q_j} f_{q_i} - h_{p_i} f_{q_i q_j} \right) \Big]\\
&\quad + \sum_{i,j} \Big[ h_{q_j} \left( f_{q_i p_j} g_{p_i} + f_{q_i} g_{p_i p_j} - f_{p_i p_j} g_{q_i} - f_{p_i} g_{q_i p_j} \right) \\
&\quad\quad - h_{p_j} \left( f_{q_i q_j} g_{p_i} + f_{q_i} g_{p_i q_j} - f_{p_i q_j} g_{q_i} - f_{p_i} g_{q_i q_j} \right) \Big]
\end{align*}
Expanding the expression:
\begin{align*}
    \{f,\{g,h\}\} + \{g,\{h,f\}\} + \{h,\{f,g\}\} = \sum_{i,j}\Big[ &+f_{q_j} g_{q_i p_j} h_{p_i} + f_{q_j} g_{q_i} h_{p_i p_j} - f_{q_j} g_{p_i p_j} h_{q_i} - f_{q_j} g_{p_i} h_{q_i p_j} \\
    - &f_{p_j} g_{q_i q_j} h_{p_i} - f_{p_j} g_{q_i} h_{p_i q_j} + f_{p_j} g_{p_i q_j} h_{q_i} + f_{p_j} g_{p_i} h_{q_i q_j} \\
    + &g_{q_j} h_{q_i p_j} f_{p_i} + g_{q_j} h_{q_i} f_{p_i p_j} - g_{q_j} h_{p_i p_j} f_{q_i} - g_{q_j} h_{p_i} f_{q_i p_j} \\
    - &g_{p_j} h_{q_i q_j} f_{p_i} - g_{p_j} h_{q_i} f_{p_i q_j} + g_{p_j} h_{p_i q_j} f_{q_i} + g_{p_j} h_{p_i} f_{q_i q_j} \\
    + &h_{q_j} f_{q_i p_j} g_{p_i} + h_{q_j} f_{q_i} g_{p_i p_j} - h_{q_j} f_{p_i p_j} g_{q_i} - h_{q_j} f_{p_i} g_{q_i p_j} \\
    - &h_{p_j} f_{q_i q_j} g_{p_i} - h_{p_j} f_{q_i} g_{p_i q_j} + h_{p_j} f_{p_i q_j} g_{q_i} + h_{p_j} f_{p_i} g_{q_i q_j}\Big]
\end{align*}
We can now see that the expression will sum to zero because for each term there exists its additive inverse. When summing over all indexes (i) and (j), the pairs sum to zero. E.g. summation of the first term of the first row and the second term of the last row:
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{i,j} f_{q_j} g_{q_i p_j} h_{p_i} -h_{p_j} f_{q_i} g_{p_i q_j} = 0\,,
\end{align*}
and the same is true for all other terms. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\{f,\{g,h\}\} + \{g,\{h,f\}\} + \{h,\{f,g\}\} = 0\,.
\end{align*}
